# How can I control volume of audio in my website?

Tags: audio, volume

I'm working on a quiz website with one feature. I want a music to continuously play while person passes a test. But I don't want the user to be able to set his device volume to low and not to hear the music. I know that I can control volume in browser, but I want to control volume of the device. Is it possible to do and how?